# Internal Energy of an ideal fermi Gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions

The internal kinetic energy of an ideal fermi gas at temperature 0K is given by $$U=\frac{3}{5}NE_f$$ What conclusion can we draw from this statement.

Comment: this is very poorly stated question. What do you want to know exactly? There are number of things we can say about that equation

Answer (score 1):

While we are waiting for clarification:

The fact that a completely degenerate gas of fermions has a non-zero kinetic energy means that even at zero temperature the fermions have momentum and can exert a pressure. This is of fundamental importance in astrophysics for explaining the nature of many phenomena including (but not limited to); providing support at the cores of low-mass stars, brown dwarfs and planets at various stages in their lives, and being responsible for the existence of white dwarf stars and (to some extent) neutron stars.

The equation also tells us that degeneracy pressure will be dependent on density (through the dependence of $E_F$ on fermion density), but *independent of temperature*. Again, this is a crucial point in many astrophysical situations, including supernova explosions.

As the internal energy does not depend on temperature, the equation also tells us that the heat capacity of a degenerate fermion gas is very small.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at is that the total internal energy is the same as though each particle has $3/5$ of the Fermi energy, even at 0K, or that each fermion has, on average, an energy of 60% of the Fermi energy. Just the fact that the fermions (e.g. electrons) *must* stack up in their energies, with no "extra" energy from heating the gas etc, gives the gas a fairly (and surprisingly) large energy - e.g. for Zinc, which has a Fermi energy of about 9.47eV, the average energy of an electron $U/N = 5.68$eV. For contrast, thermal energies at room temperature are about $1/40$ eV.

Comment: As it stands, this does not really provide an answer to the question. Maybe you want to rephrase from a question to a statement and expand a little?